# Popover directive in angular 2.0

Tags: angular

I am facing issue using bootstrap popover in angular 2.0. Any example of using bootstrap popover in angular 2.0. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you add some information about what's not working and what you've tried so far?  It's very difficult to offer help when we aren't sure what the problem is.